# How can I refactor an existing source code file to normalize all use of tab?

Tags: refactoring

Sometimes I find myself editing a C source file which sees both use of tab as four spaces, and regular tab.

Is there any tool that attempts to parse the file and "normalize" this, i.e. convert all occurrences of four spaces to regular tab, or all occurrences of tab to four spaces, to keep it consistent?

I assume something like this can be done even with just a simple vim one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

There's [`:retab`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aretab) and `:retab!` which can help, but there are caveats.

It's easier if you're using spaces for indentation, then just set [`'expandtab'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27) and execute `:retab`, then all your tabs will be converted to spaces at the appropriate tab stops (which default to 8.) That's easy and there are no traps in this method!

If you want to use 4 space indentation, then keep `'expandtab'` enabled and set [`'softtabstop'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27softtabstop%27) to 4. (Avoid modifying the `'tabstop'` option, it should always stay at 8.)

If you want to do the inverse and convert to tabs instead, you *could* set `'noexpandtab'` and then use `:retab!` (which will also look at sequences of spaces and try to convert them back to tabs.) The main problem with this approach is that it won't just consider indentation for conversion, but also sequences of spaces in the middle of lines, which can cause the operation to affect strings inside your code, which would be highly undesirable.

Perhaps a better approach for replacing spaces with tabs for indentation is to use the following substitute command:

```
:%s#^\s\+#\=repeat("\t", indent('.') / &tabstop).repeat(" ", indent('.') % &tabstop)#
```

Yeah it's a mouthful... It's matching whitespace at the beginning of the lines, then using the `indent()` function to find the total indentation (that function calculates indentation taking tab stops in consideration), then dividing that by the `'tabstop'` to decide how many tabs and how many spaces a specific line needs.

If this command works for you, you might want to consider adding a mapping or `:command` for it, to keep it handy. For example:

```
command! -range=% Retab <line1>,<line2>s#^\s\+#\=repeat("\t", indent('.') / &tabstop).repeat(" ", indent('.') % &tabstop)
```

This also allows you to "Retab" a range of the file, including one you select with a visual selection.

Finally, one last alternative to `:retab` is that to ask Vim to "reformat" your code completely, using the [`=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3D) command, which will use the current `'indentexpr'` or other indentation configurations such as `'cindent'` to completely reindent the block. That typically respects your `'noexpandtab'` and `'smarttabstop'` options, so it use tabs and spaces for indentation consistently. The downside of this approach is that it will completely reformat your code, including changing indentation in places. The upside is that it typically has a semantic understanding of the language and will be able to take that in consideration when reindenting the code block.